# How ro run Prebid.js Native ads without an ad server?

Tags: ads, native-ads, prebid.js, header-bidding

I've successfully implemented banners in Prebid.js without an ad server following this documentation: https://docs.prebid.org/dev-docs/examples/no-adserver.html but I can't find out any information about implementing Native ads without an ad server. Does anyone have any information about this?